# Writing some basic sentences in the language of set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having some trouble proving that some basic sentences in the language $L_\in$ of first order set theory are $\Sigma_1$ or $\Pi_1$, the reason being that I do not know how exactly to write them. Unfortunately in most books dealing with ranks $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ this knowledge is assumed which makes my life complicated.

Now an introduction. Every quantifier free formula is $\Delta_0$. If $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are $\Delta_0$ then so is $\phi\wedge\varphi$ and $\neg\phi$ and finally if $\varphi$ is $\Delta_0$ then $(\exists x)(x\in y\wedge \phi)$ is also $\Delta_0$. A formula is $\Sigma_1$ if of the form $(\exists x)\phi$ for $\phi\in\Delta_0$ and in $\Pi_1$ if can we writen as $(\forall x)\phi$ for $\phi\in\Delta_0$.

I would like to see that the following sentences are $\Sigma_1$ formulas:

1) $\alpha$ is not a cardinal (initial ordinal)

2) $cf(\alpha)\leq \beta$

3) $\alpha$ is singular.

4) $|x|\leq |y|$

And the following are $\Pi_1$:

1) $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

2) $cf(\alpha)$ is regular.

3) $\alpha$ is weakly inaccessible

4) $y=P(x)$

The first one for example asks to write "$\alpha$ is an ordinal and there is $\beta <\alpha$ and a surjection from $\beta$ to $\alpha$". So it could be written as as "exists $f$ function such that for some $\beta<\alpha$, $f$ is a surjection form $\beta$ to $\alpha$". Now this I can see as $\Sigma_1$ formula, however I still doubt if the solution is correct.

Other question arise like, given $x$ and $y$ fixed, if we range a variable among functions with domain in $x$ and range in $y$, is that not a bounded quantifier? That is, is the sentence "$(\exists f)(f \text{ is a function } \wedge dom(f)\subset x \wedge rg(f)\subset y$)" in $\Delta_0$?